# How does Spring dependency injection work inside a class that is annotated @Component but any without constructor annotation?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

My code is working but I'm not able to figure from where I'm getting dependency injection. As Spring documentation mentions nothing about default dependency injection.

```
package org.stackoverflow; 


@Component 
public class A {
    private final B b;
    public A(B b) {
      this.b = b;
    }
}

package org.segfault; 


@Configuration
Public class Config {
   @Bean 
   public B b(){ return new B(); }
}
```

As in above code component scan is running on the path com.stackoverflow and imported org.segfault class config. But as you can see there no constructor injection in class A.

I suspect it must be documented somewhere. But I'm not able to find out. Anyway, it's working :)

Can someone help with documentation or Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Spring documentation**, chapter [17. Spring Beans and Dependency Injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html) says:

> If a bean has one constructor, you can omit the `@Autowired`

Answer (score 1):

Since Spring `4.3.*`, specifying the `@Autowire` annotation above the constructor isn't needed anymore, provided that there is a **single**, **non-private** constructor for the class.

> **6.1 Core Container Improvements** ([news](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#new-in-4.3))
>   It is no longer necessary to specify the `@Autowired` annotation if the target bean only defines one constructor.